# Read and write the content of file 10 times

Tags: c, file

I have a text file `"hello.txt"`, I need to read that file and write to `stdout` 10 times, how can I do that?

What I am doing presently is as follows:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
 int c,i;
 FILE *fp;
 for(i=0;i<10;++i) {
    fp = fopen("hello.txt","r");
    for(;c!=EOF;c= getc(fp),putchar(c));
    fclose(fp);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

This code is printing contents only 1 time but *not* 10 times.

Comment: a good practice is to try and debug program to find errors .

Comment: The code already runs into undefined behaviour when entering the loop for the first time, as `c` is test against `EOF` without having been initialise prior to this. Reading an uninitialised variable provokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is that at the end of first iteration value of variable  `c` becomes  EOF, and in all next iterations loop break due to `c != EOF` for loop's condition and couldn't print any char. In-fact you are using uninitialized `c` in comparison that causes undefined behavior in your code as @[alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576) notice and also [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807998/read-and-write-the-content-of-file-10-times#comment33002455_21807998) to your question.

You should (re-)initialise `c` at starting of each for loop.

Replace:

```
for(;c!=EOF;c= getc(fp),putchar(c));
```

by:

```
for(c = getc(fp); c != EOF; putchar(c), c= getc(fp));
 // ^^ always initialize    ^^          ^^ swap order
```

Additionally, if you want to read a file again and again then **better approach** is to use [`void rewind ( FILE * stream );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/)  function, You need to rewind file pointer to the beginning of the file at the end of loop, something like:

```
 fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");
 for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for(c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp), putchar(c));
    rewind(fp); 
 }
 fclose(fp);
```

**Note**: To make code readable use space after `;` and `,`.

Comment: Not really nitpicking: `reinitialise` should better be `(re-)initialise`. Please see my comment to the OP.

Comment: @alk Yes, you are correct I even didn't notice.  Now I added in my answer Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
 int c,i;
 FILE *fp;
 for(i=0;i<10;++i) {
    fp = fopen("hello.txt","r");
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
      putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(fp);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

As when in your code `c` becomes EOF the loop will forever be ignored!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan- Nope - Last line needs context

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize `c` before reading file again. In your code once `c` is `EOF` it stays it forever and does not go in `for` loop.

```
c = 0;
for(;c!=EOF;c= getc(fp),putchar(c));
```